# Turkish character bug in mb_strtoupper function of PHP

Tags: php, utf-8, character, turkish

My question is rather explanation for the Turkish colleges who have troubles with our funny characters.

It is for sure PHP 5 has a **bug** by capitalizing and also therefore collating them.

echo mb_strtoupper('Turkish capitals for ğ, i, ı, ş in uppercase', 'UTF-8');

gives the result: "TURKISH CAPITALS FOR Ğ, I, I, Ş IN UPPERCASE".

But it is wrong. The correct output should be "TURKİSH CAPİTALS FOR Ğ, İ, I, Ş İN UPPERCASE"

The problem in our language we have "i" in capitals "İ" and "ı" in capitals "I".

I guess you see the problem.

Whom shall we report this **bug** in PHP, does anybody know? Please inform and if you write a subroutine to solve this problem temporarily, it will be appreciated. Thanks ahead.

Comment: You can report bugs here: https://bugs.php.net/report.php

Comment: This is related post in PHP bug page: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=70072&thanks=7

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Can you try this:

```
function pre_up($str){
    $str = str_replace('i', 'İ', $str);
    $str = str_replace('ı', 'I', $str);
    return $str;
}
echo mb_strtoupper(pre_up('Turkish capitals for ğ, i, ı, ş in uppercase'), 'UTF-8');
```

I don't know Turkish, is it correct?

**Output**

> TURKİSH CAPİTALS FOR Ğ, İ, I, Ş İN UPPERCASE

Answer (score 10):

`mb_strtoupper` is not locale aware. For handling these sorts of transformations you can use a [`Transliterator`](http://php.net/transliterator) which is, e.g.:

```
echo Transliterator::create("tr-Upper")
    ->transliterate('Turkish capitals for ğ, i, ı, ş in uppercase');
```

outputs:

```
TURKİSH CAPİTALS FOR Ğ, İ, I, Ş İN UPPERCASE
```

Comment: I am sorry I could not check your solution, it may be correct as well. Thank you.

Comment: This is better answer, since you don't need custom function and is more general solution.

Comment: This is very clear solution. Thanks @user3942918

Comment: Transliterator::create("tr-Title")  is for uppercase first character

Answer (score 0):

you can write your own function for do this:

```
function trkish_upper($str){
    $find = array('i', 'ı'); //any turkish chars
    $replace = array('İ','I');
    $new = str_replace($find,$replace,$str);
    return $new;
}
```

Comment: I am sorry I could not check your solution, it may be correct as well. Thank you.